# Netlogo reading from file

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to read these values from a file,

```
[-1 -5 270]
[-2 -5 270]
[-3 -5 270]
[-4 -5 270]
[-5 -5 270]
```

I need to get the first, second and third value from each line.

Comment: It is reading each line as a string, i need to get numbers from the line.

Comment: What have you already tried? Let us see your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file, Read it in like any other file. Then, use the file-read to read the line in. The format you provide seems to be in the same format as a list, so you can just interpret the line directly. As a side note, if not, you could do something like read-line to get the line as a string and parse it however you want.

Then use the list extraction operator to get items from the relevant indices.

```
file-open “filename.txt”
while [not file-at-end?]
[
    let line file-read
    show item 0 line
    show item 1 line
    show item 2 line
]
file-close
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, do you know if its possible to make netlogo see item 0 as X and item 1 as Y?

Comment: like assigning a previously named variable named x or the x coordinate ?

Comment: I think so, i have been asked by my supervisor to try and make the program see the numbers being read in as an xcor, ycor values.

Comment: setxy (item 0 line) (item 1 line) or set xcor (item 0 line) set ycor (item 1 line)

Comment: Thank you for your help, Is it also possible to store them in an array straigt from the file, so the first number is stored in an array call x, y and direction?

Comment: Do you mean a list? or an array? Those two are different. For the former, you should look into csv:from-file